I have a code that works for one Dataset but returns an empty array for another set of Data
I wanna start this by saying that I am still learning how to code. So if there is an obvious solution to my problem I might have just not thought about because I don't know that much yet. I have another former Master student that helps me but she is also a bit out of her depth with the Problem...
The Problem: For my Master I am analyzing a set of video Data. I used DLC to generate Whisker tracking and am now trying to analyze the movement of the Whiskers in the videos. For that I have code that calculates the angle and speed of the left and right whiskers for each frame and at the end I want to plot the angle and speed two seconds (200 frames) before and after an LED signal in the video.
I have fone that for one set of videos. Now I wanted to do it for another set of Videos where the only difference is that the original Data is in two sets of timestamps rather then one (both using the same clock so that the timestamp in the video_ttls is the same as the opto_ttls) but now the Code has decided to return an empty array at the very end where previously I had no problems.
Below I will post the whole code I am using (if its ugly I apologize, it is my first real programming outside of some R statistics.)
import numpy as np  
# https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html for scientific computing provides a multidimensional array object, various derived objectsand an assortment of routines for fast operations on arrays 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  # comprehensive library for creating static, animated, and interactive visualizations
import pandas as pd   # functions for analyzing, cleaning, exploring, and manipulating
import os as os   # OS Modul in Python gibt dir Zugriff auf einige Funktionen des Betriebssystems
from astropy.convolution import Gaussian1DKernel, convolve  # convolution functions and kernels that offer improvements compared to the SciPy scipy.ndimage convolution routines
import math
import pickle
from glob import glob
from tqdm import tqdm #tqdm (read taqadum, تقدّم) means “progress” in arabic. Instantly make your loops show a progress meter - just wrap any iterable with “tqdm(iterable)”, and you’re done!



dlc_whiskers = 'E:/DLC/analysis/H5ThisOne/'#Day3/Day3-1DLC_resnet50_WhiskersApr30shuffle1_200000_filtered.h5'
cam = "cam0_2023-05-16"
motion_files = glob(dlc_whiskers + cam  + "/cam0_2023-05-16" +'*filtered.h5') # this will get the path of all the h5 file having the date of interest



video_data = np.load("e:/DLC/analysis/opto/ttls_opto/2023-05-16/camera_ttl.npy")
opto_data = np.load("e:/DLC/analysis/opto/ttls_opto/2023-05-16/opto_ttl_cont.npy", allow_pickle = True)
opto = opto_data.item()
# opto_data is a 0-dimensional array, so i need to extract the dictionary if i want to access it properly which is opto = opto_data.item()
led_times_left = opto ["ttl_opto_left"]
led_times_right = opto ["ttl_opto_right"]

differences_left = np.abs(video_data[:, None] - led_times_left[None, :])  # Shape: (len(video_data), len(first_value))
closest_indices_left = np.argmin(differences_left, axis=0)  # Shape: (len(first_value),)

differences_right = np.abs(video_data[:, None] - led_times_right[None, :])  # Shape: (len(video_data), len(first_value))
closest_indices_right = np.argmin(differences_right, axis=0)  # Shape: (len(first_value),)
# the closest indices arrays contain all the indices in which the video data is closest to either opto_left or opto_right


right_whisker_tip_x = np.array([])
right_whisker_tip_y = np.array([])
right_whisker_tip_p = np.array([])
right_whisker_middle_x = np.array([])
right_whisker_middle_y = np.array([])
right_whisker_middle_p = np.array([])
right_whisker_end_x = np.array([])
right_whisker_end_y = np.array([])
right_whisker_end_p = np.array([])
left_whisker_tip_x = np.array([])
left_whisker_tip_y = np.array([])
left_whisker_tip_p = np.array([])
left_whisker_middle_x = np.array([])
left_whisker_middle_y = np.array([])
left_whisker_middle_p = np.array([])
left_whisker_end_x = np.array([])
left_whisker_end_y = np.array([])
left_whisker_end_p = np.array([])
Nose_x = np.array([])
Nose_y = np.array([])
Nose_p = np.array([])



for motion_file in motion_files:
    dlc_tmp = pd.read_hdf(motion_file)
    dlc_d = dlc_tmp.keys()[0][0]
    data = eval('dlc_tmp.'+dlc_d)
    left_whisker_tip_x = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_tip_x, data['TipLeft']['x']))
    left_whisker_tip_y = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_tip_y, data['TipLeft']['y']))
    left_whisker_tip_p = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_tip_p, data['TipLeft']['likelihood']))
    left_whisker_middle_x = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_middle_x, data['MiddleLeft']['x']))
    left_whisker_middle_y = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_middle_y, data['MiddleLeft']['y']))
    left_whisker_middle_p = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_middle_p, data['MiddleLeft']['likelihood']))
    left_whisker_end_x =np.concatenate (( left_whisker_end_p, data['EndLeft']['x']))
    left_whisker_end_y = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_end_p, data['EndLeft']['y']))
    left_whisker_end_p = np.concatenate (( left_whisker_end_p, data['EndLeft']['likelihood']))


for motion_file in motion_files:
    dlc_tmp = pd.read_hdf(motion_file)
    dlc_d = dlc_tmp.keys()[0][0]
    data = eval('dlc_tmp.'+dlc_d)
    right_whisker_tip_x = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_tip_x, data['TipRight']['x']))
    right_whisker_tip_y = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_tip_y, data['TipRight']['y']))
    right_whisker_tip_p = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_tip_p, data['TipRight']['likelihood']))
    right_whisker_middle_x = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_middle_x, data['MiddleRight']['x']))
    right_whisker_middle_y = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_middle_y, data['MiddleRight']['y']))
    right_whisker_middle_p = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_middle_p, data['MiddleRight']['likelihood']))
    right_whisker_end_x =np.concatenate (( right_whisker_end_p, data['EndRight']['x']))
    right_whisker_end_y = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_end_p, data['EndRight']['y']))
    right_whisker_end_p = np.concatenate (( right_whisker_end_p, data['EndRight']['likelihood']))
    Nose_x = np.concatenate (( Nose_x, data['Nose']['x']))
    Nose_y = np.concatenate (( Nose_y, data['Nose']['y']))
    Nose_p = np.concatenate (( Nose_p, data['Nose']['likelihood']))

num_frames = len(Nose_x)

# Get slopes and intercepts

def fit_lines_opt_right(right_whisker_tip_x, right_whisker_middle_x, right_whisker_end_x, right_whisker_tip_y, right_whisker_middle_y, right_whisker_end_y):

# using arrays instead of df makes the processing faster

    # using premade (preallocated) empty arrays to fill later for slopes and intercepts

    slopes_right = np.empty(num_frames)
    intercepts_right = np.empty(num_frames)

    
    for i in tqdm(range(num_frames)):
        all_r_x = np.array([right_whisker_tip_x[i],right_whisker_middle_x[i], right_whisker_end_x[i]])
        all_r_y = np.array([right_whisker_tip_y[i], right_whisker_middle_y[i], right_whisker_end_y[i]])
        
        
        slope_right, intercept_right = np.polyfit(all_r_x, all_r_y, 1)
        slopes_right[i] = slope_right
        intercepts_right[i] = intercept_right    


    return slopes_right, intercepts_right       


def fit_lines_opt_left(left_whisker_tip_x, left_whisker_middle_x, left_whisker_end_x, left_whisker_tip_y, left_whisker_middle_y, left_whisker_end_y):

# using arrays instead of df makes the processing faster

    # using premade (preallocated) empty arrays to fill later for slopes and intercepts


    slopes_left = np.empty(num_frames)
    intercepts_left = np.empty(num_frames)
    
    for i in tqdm(range(num_frames)):

        all_l_x = np.array([left_whisker_tip_x[i], left_whisker_middle_x[i], left_whisker_end_x[i]])
        all_l_y = np.array([left_whisker_tip_y[i], left_whisker_middle_y[i], left_whisker_end_y[i]])

        slope_left, intercept_left = np.polyfit(all_l_x, all_l_y, 1)
        slopes_left[i] = slope_left
        intercepts_left[i] = intercept_left  

    return  slopes_left, intercepts_left        

slopes_right, intercepts_right = fit_lines_opt_right(right_whisker_tip_x, right_whisker_middle_x, right_whisker_end_x, right_whisker_tip_y, right_whisker_middle_y, right_whisker_end_y)
slopes_left, intercepts_left = fit_lines_opt_left(left_whisker_tip_x, left_whisker_middle_x, left_whisker_end_x, left_whisker_tip_y, left_whisker_middle_y, left_whisker_end_y)


nose_slope = np.zeros(len(Nose_x)) # array len of Nose filled with 0


print ("Slopes done")


def angls(nose_slope, slopes_right, slopes_left):


    PI = np.pi #needed to convert red to deg
    M1 = nose_slope 
    M2 = slopes_right 
    M3 = slopes_left

    val_r = np.empty(len(nose_slope))  # memory-wise always better to create an empty array of the right size than an empty list that you always expand
    val_l = np.empty(len(nose_slope))
    for i in range (num_frames):       
        angl_r = (M1[i] - M2[i]) / (1 + M2[i] * M1[i])
        angl_l = (M1[i] - M3[i]) / (1 + M3[i] * M1[i])
        ret_r = math.atan (np.abs(angl_r)) # tan inverse of angle
        ret_l = math.atan (np.abs(angl_l)) # tan inverse of angle

        val_r[i] = (ret_r * 180) / PI # converts rad to deg 
        val_l[i] = (ret_l * 180) / PI
    return val_r, val_l

val_r, val_l = angls(nose_slope, slopes_right, slopes_left)


avrg_r = np.mean(val_r)
avrg_l = np.mean(val_l)
# This is what I did for the whiskers speed 
val_speed_r = np.gradient(val_r)
val_speed_l = np.gradient(val_l)
print("val done")


differences_left = np.abs(video_data[:, None] - led_times_left[None, :])  # Shape: (len(video_data), len(first_value))
closest_indices_left = np.argmin(differences_left, axis=0)  # Shape: (len(first_value),)

differences_right = np.abs(video_data[:, None] - led_times_right[None, :])  # Shape: (len(video_data), len(first_value))
closest_indices_right = np.argmin(differences_right, axis=0)  # Shape: (len(first_value),)
# the closest indices arrays contain all the indices in which the video data is closest to either opto_left or opto_right
led_times_left  = video_data[closest_indices_left]

led_times_right = video_data[ closest_indices_right]


thr = 5

above_idx_r = np.where(val_speed_r>=thr)[0]
above_diff_r = np.diff(above_idx_r)
gaps_r = np.where(above_diff_r>300)[0]

above_idx_l = np.where(val_speed_l>=thr)[0]
above_diff_l = np.diff(above_idx_l)
gaps_l = np.where(above_diff_l>300)[0]


onsets_og_r = above_idx_r[gaps_r]
onsets_og_l = above_idx_l[gaps_l+1]


def motion_around_timestamps(motion, timestamps, window_in_ms = [-2, 2]):
    
    window = np.array(window_in_ms)*300
    motion_all = []

    for onset in timestamps:
        if onset + int(window[1]) < len(motion):
            tmp = motion[onset+int(window[0]):onset+ int(window[1])].copy()
            motion_all.append(tmp)

    if len(motion_all) == 0:
        return motion_all, np.zeros((window[1] - window[0]))  # Handle empty motion_all gracefully

    return motion_all, np.mean(motion_all, axis = 0)


speed_r = np.gradient(val_r)    
indiv_r, velocity_av_r = motion_around_timestamps(val_speed_r,onsets_og_r , window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_angl_r, angl_av_r = motion_around_timestamps(val_r,onsets_og_r , window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_angl_led_r, angl_av_led_r = motion_around_timestamps(val_r,led_times_right , window_in_ms = [-2 , 2])
indiv_angl_led_r = np.array(indiv_angl_led_r)


speed_l = np.gradient(val_l)    
indiv_l, velocity_av_l = motion_around_timestamps(val_speed_l,onsets_og_l , window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_angl_l, angl_av_l = motion_around_timestamps(val_l,onsets_og_l , window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_angl_led_l, angl_av_led_l = motion_around_timestamps(val_l,led_times_left, window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_angl_led_l = np.array(indiv_angl_led_l)


indiv_speed_led_r, speed_av_led_r = motion_around_timestamps(speed_r,led_times_right, window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_speed_led_r = np.array(indiv_speed_led_r)

indiv_speed_led_l, speed_av_led_l = motion_around_timestamps(speed_l,led_times_left, window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
indiv_speed_led_l = np.array(indiv_speed_led_l)


At the end of the Code i need an array for the indiv_angl_led_l and indiv_angl_led_r (which should be the angl of the left and right whisker around the specific timestamps in led_time_left/ led_time_right) so that I may plot those.
I tried adjusting the thr i tried going with only part of the led_times_left in the function and tried adjusting the
def_motion_around_timestamps() bit as well but nothing worked.
I dont get an error or anything, for a bit I got a warning (that has since stopped appearing) but if I look at print(indiv_angl_led_r) i just get []
Whereas if I look at the indiv_ang_led_r for the video_data I already analyzed !with the exact same code! I have a bunch of numbers (that then got plotted)

It has been solved now!
In case anyone cares: indiv_angl_led_l, angl_av_led_l = motion_around_timestamps(val_l,closest_indices_left, window_in_ms = [-2, 2])
this is what fixed it
